# How to merge Json arrays in a new array

Tags: python, json, pandas, selenium

I'm messing around with web scrapers for fun and I have a simple web scraper that extracts some data from https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed, when I save all this data in a JSON file it looks like this:

```
    "date": {
      "0": "13-08-2021",
      "1": "22-08-2021",
      "2": "28-08-2021",
      "3": "11-09-2021"
    },
    "team_1": {
      "0": "Brentford",
      "1": "Arsenal",
      "2": "Man City",
      "3": "Arsenal"
    },
    "results": {
      "0": "2 - 0",
      "1": "0 - 2",
      "2": "5 - 0",
      "3": "1 - 0"
    },
    "team_2": {
      "0": "Arsenal",
      "1": "Chelsea",
      "2": "Arsenal",
      "3": "Norwich"
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is any way I can merge the arrays, or how I can change the code so the new object looks like this:

```
{
      "date": "13-08-2021",
      "Team_1": "Brentford",
      "results": "2 - 0",
      "Team_2": "Arsenal",
}
{
      "date": "22-08-2021",
      "Team_1": "Arsenal",
      "results": "0 - 2",
      "Team_2": "Chelsea",
}
```

Here's the Python code:

```
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'

s = Service('C:...\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(website)
all_matches_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@analytics-event="All matches"]')
all_matches_button.click()

matches = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

date = []
team_1 = []
results = []
team_2 = []

for match in matches:
    date.append(match.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text)
    team_1.append(match.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text)
    results.append(match.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]').text)
    team_2.append(match.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]').text)
    print(team_1)

driver.quit()

data_frame = pd.dataFrame({'date' : date, 'team_1' : team_1, 'results' : results, 'team_2' : team_2 })
data_frame.to_json('results.json')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas library for easy transition

```
import pandas as pd

matches = {
    "date": {
      "0": "13-08-2021",
      "1": "22-08-2021",
      "2": "28-08-2021",
      "3": "11-09-2021"
    },
    "team_1": {
      "0": "Brentford",
      "1": "Arsenal",
      "2": "Man City",
      "3": "Arsenal"
    },
    "results": {
      "0": "2 - 0",
      "1": "0 - 2",
      "2": "5 - 0",
      "3": "1 - 0"
    },
    "team_2": {
      "0": "Arsenal",
      "1": "Chelsea",
      "2": "Arsenal",
      "3": "Norwich"
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(matches)

macth_results = df.T.to_dict()

""" Result
{'0': {'date': '13-08-2021',
  'team_1': 'Brentford',
  'results': '2 - 0',
  'team_2': 'Arsenal'},
 '1': {'date': '22-08-2021',
  'team_1': 'Arsenal',
  'results': '0 - 2',
  'team_2': 'Chelsea'},
 '2': {'date': '28-08-2021',
  'team_1': 'Man City',
  'results': '5 - 0',
  'team_2': 'Arsenal'},
 '3': {'date': '11-09-2021',
  'team_1': 'Arsenal',
  'results': '1 - 0',
  'team_2': 'Norwich'}}
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `orient='records'` option to [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {'0': '13-08-2021', '1': '22-08-2021', '2': '28-08-2021', '3': '11-09-2021'}, 'team_1': {'0': 'Brentford', '1': 'Arsenal', '2': 'Man City', '3': 'Arsenal'}, 'results': {'0': '2 - 0', '1': '0 - 2', '2': '5 - 0', '3': '1 - 0'}, 'team_2': {'0': 'Arsenal', '1': 'Chelsea', '2': 'Arsenal', '3': 'Norwich'}})
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
'[
 {"date":"13-08-2021","team_1":"Brentford","results":"2 - 0","team_2":"Arsenal"},
 {"date":"22-08-2021","team_1":"Arsenal","results":"0 - 2","team_2":"Chelsea"},
 {"date":"28-08-2021","team_1":"Man City","results":"5 - 0","team_2":"Arsenal"},
 {"date":"11-09-2021","team_1":"Arsenal","results":"1 - 0","team_2":"Norwich"}
]'
```